# I am a beginner programmer and I cant solve easy problem. Could you fix the code

Tags: java, loops

The problem

The program receives as input a sequence of non-negative integers, each number is written on a separate line. The sequence ends with the number 0, upon reading which the program must finish its work and print the length of the sequence (not counting the terminating number 0).

Numbers following 0 do not need to be read.

Input Format

A sequence of integers is entered, ending with the number 0 (the number 0 itself is not included in the sequence).

Constraints

Each number in the sequence is integer, positive, not exceeding 1000.

Output Format

Print the answer to the problem.

Sample Input 0

1

7

9

0

5

Sample Output 0

3

My code

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String result=("");
        do{
            int a = scan.nextInt();
            int b=a;
            String s=String.valueOf(b);
            result = (result + s);
        }while(a>0);
        int length = result.length();
        System.out.println(length);
    }
}
```

The output tells

```
Solution.java:14: error: variable a is already defined in method main(String[])
            int a = scan.nextInt();
                ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define your variables outside the while loop because otherwise as the error message tells you, you're going to redefine them.

Just put

```java
int a = -1;
int b = -1;
String s = null;
```

before your loop and reference these variables inside your loop.

In addition you need a guard clause for appending to your result, otherwise the zero marking the end of the sequence will be included in your count.

```
if (a > 0) {
  result += s;
}
```

Furthermore if you only want to count until zero, you du not need the result variable and then print the length of it but can use an integer for counting and increase this integer by one in each loop execution.

Edit:
Sample implementation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    while(scan.nextInt() > 0){
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```